# Select a dynamic range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to record a macro that will select a range of cells where the first cell (A3) is consistent, but the last cell changes from sheet to sheet. I started by recording a macro with the ending cell already selected, but it doesn't work from sheet to sheet. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at `Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)`

Answer (score 0):

This will select from A3 to the bottom of data in column A:

```
Sub cutaneous()
    Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Select
End Sub
```